# Can I read in a character without the return key 'n'? (C)

Tags: c, scanf, return-value, carriage-return

Im trying to verify if the user enters the right value with the return values.
He should enter an even number between 0 and 100.

I think I got it right, but now my problem is, that the user has to enter the "enter" key twice to end the scanf function.

Do I have another possibility to avoid the user from doing so?

Heres the code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h> 

int main( void )
{
   int ok, input = -1;
   char c;

   while(input < 1 || input > 100 || input%2 != 0) {      //repeat loop if Input is not even or betwenn 0 and 100
       printf("Enter an odd number between 1 und 100: ");
       int ok = scanf("%d%c", &input, &c);                //Input is correct if ok = 2 and c = 10'\n'

       while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {}      //this loop empties the input buffer to avoid infinite loops if users enters a character         
   }                                                                        

   printf("You habe chosen the number %d ", input);

   getchar(); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Capture characters from standard input without waiting for enter to be pressed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/421860/capture-characters-from-standard-input-without-waiting-for-enter-to-be-pressed)

Comment: "*the user has to enter the "enter" key twice to end the scanf function*" - are you sure it is `scanf()` that is waiting? The `%c` will read an Enter, and `getchar()` will wait for another Enter. So you need at least 2 Enters for your outer loop to validate the input. Why do you have `scanf()` reading an Enter at all? On a side note, I would suggest using a `do..while` loop instead, do the validation only after `scanf()` is called, not before it is called.

Comment: Another way to avoid infinite loops is to use `fgets` to read a line, and `sscanf` or `strtol` to extract the number. Reading the entire line first means that there's no mess to clean up if extracting the number fails.

Comment: You read, but overlooked `ok` which BTW suggests you think it is a boolean result. It's the number of items successfully converted, which here must be `2`.

Comment: You'll want to stop using `scanf()` for everything under the sun. There's other functions that give you a lot more control.

Comment: @remylebeau that was very useful thank you! Im reading the enter, to make sure that the user only enters a number, if he enters a character I would see that in the c variable. I cant use a do...while loop cause the professor wanted us to solve it using only the while loop, dont ask me why...

Comment: @user338609 Thanks for your answer! I didnt reach fgets and sscanf in my lessons so Im only using the functions that I know :)

Comment: @tadman Thanks for your answer! I didnt reach fgets and sscanf in my lessons so Im only using the functions that I know :)

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for answering! 2 questions asked and you commented in both of them. Thats a curious coincidence :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you don't need the second while loop at all.

As suggested above, the `scanf()` is waiting for enter to be pressed once, and then `getchar()` is waiting after.

If you remove the second while loop, the code should run correctly and only require the enter key to be pressed once.

I hope this helps!

Comment: There are 2 `while` loops. You didn't say which one to remove. But the requirements say: "He should enter an even number between 0 and 100". The outer `while` loop is being used to ensure that the user actually enters a value in that range. The inner `while` loop is being used to read characters until Enter is reached. It doesn't really make sense to remove either loop. If anything, the `%c` needs to be removed from the `scanf()` instead

Comment: Good point, I've classified which while loop I mean in my answer. However I do think it should work without the second one. The %c will remove '\n' from the input so the second while loop just isn't needed.

Comment: the `%c` won't catch an Enter if the user types in something else after the number and before an Enter. But the inner loop will.

Comment: @RemyLebeau you are right! Removing %c from scanf solved my problem!